# Mouse position not detected on mouse click for playing sound with Lua in Love2D

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm writing a little game for visual deficient people, but I'm having a hard time getting the mouse position. Let me explain :

I need to know where in the table the mouse cursor is, without having a click, and then I want to play a sound. That sound would be different for every position. Any thoughts? Thanks, in advance!

e.g., when the mouse is on the 1st box would be played the audio "a1", when it's on the 2nd box, "a2", and so on.

I tried with:

```
mouse_x, mouse_y = get_Position()

if mouse_x and mouse_y == map[x][y] then
if map[x][y] == 0.1 then
Audio:play()
```

But it makes a loop and the sound keeps playing forever!

Comment: What scripting environment (host application) you are using?

Comment: I'm using Love2D

Comment: Is [this](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.mouse.getCursor) what u r looking for?

Comment: @csaar, I tried that, but it didn't work. I got better results with getPosition(), but it get inside a loop. I added some info to the original post, take a look, please.

Comment: I don't know, if you know what you are really doing there. Firstly line 1 doesn't conform to the syntax. It should be `mouse_x, mouse_y = get_Position()`. `==` is a conditional operand.
Your first condition evaluates, if `mouse_x` has any value and if `mouse_y` has the same value like `map[x][y]`. Is this your intention?
I'll recommend to debug the variables and the value of get_position().

Comment: Yeah, the first line is my mistake. But what I want is to play a sound saying "a1" when the mouse is moved to the 1st box, "a2" to the 2nd box, and so on...

Comment: Would it help if I posted the entire code?

Comment: `if mouse_x and mouse_y == map[x][y] then if map[x][y] == 0.1 then` is equivalent to `if  (mouse_x~=nil) and  (mouse_y==0.1)`.  Also, I believe `if-then` must be followed by `end` in the correct Lua code. The code above has no loops so it is impossible to say why it is looping. Minimal complete examples are preferred over full code dumps, but if you cannot localize the problem, well, entire code has better chance of answer than the current snippet.

Comment: `if mouse_x and mouse_y == map[x][y]` this probably doesn't do what you think. Lua reads that as `if (mouse_x) and (mouse_y == map[x][y])`, in other words: "If mouse_x is neither false nor nil, and mouse_y is exactly equal to map[x][y], then..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think part of the problem relates to how precise love2d is able to be with it's mouse.

You'll most likely have to change some of the logic in your code around to be more like

(There's four different scenario's because of the ordering in house 1 and 2 would be assigned)

```
if map.x1 < mouse_x < map.x2 and map.y1 < mouse_y < map.y2 or
map.x1 > mouse_x > map.x2 and map.y1 > mouse_y > map.y2 or
map.x1 < mouse_x < map.x2 and map.y1 > mouse_y > map.y2 or
map.x1 > mouse_x > map.x2 and map.y1 < mouse_y < map.y2 then
     TEsound.play(soundList, "a1", 1, 0.1)
end
```

Here's an image that explains detecting if the mouse for an eraser is overlapping with a line.

[image]

With only 2 x and y coordinates, that example above will probably all be too precise, and you may have to expand the range that the mouse reaches by adding and subtracting small numbers on each side of the inequality.

```
if (map.x1 - 2 < mouse_x and map.x2 + 2 > mouse_x and map.y1 - 2 < mouse_y and map.y2 + 2 > mouse_y)
            or (map.x1 + 2 > mouse_x and map.x2 - 2 < mouse_x and map.y1 + 2 > mouse_y and map.y2 - 2 < mouse_y)
            or (map.x1 - 2 < mouse_x and map.x2 + 2 > mouse_x and map.y1 + 2 > mouse_y and map.y2 - 2 < mouse_y)
            or (map.x1 + 2 > mouse_x and map.x2 - 2 < mouse_x and map.y1 - 2 < mouse_y and map.y2 + 2 > mouse_y)
```

Or another option would be to use 4 x coordinate's and 4 y coordinates, assuming your selecting a 2D area

Comment: @Newton If this didn't help you, leave a comment and I'll try to explain more