# Mouse click event is not working in love2d lua engine

Tags: lua, love2d

I am trying to make a hold system in `love2d`. When the left button of the mouse is pressed and it is in the object `hitbox`, it activates the holding event, but the functions for working with mouse click is not working

I am using `love 0.9.1` and already tried using `love.mouse.isDown` and `love.mousepressed`.

I have tried with my own code and with the examples in `love2d` `wiki` and my mouse is working well, it's not a hardware problem

It is actually not doing nothing, mouse does not working.

Comment: Your love is 0.9.1?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to post your code for anyone to know what's not working about it, but [here's another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633048/getting-mouse-position-and-playing-sound-with-lua-in-love2d/53699758#53699758) where someone couldn't get their mouse clicks working that I answered, and that might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Using `love.mouse.isDown("l")` (or `love.mouse.isDown('l')`) instead of `love.mouse.isDown(1)` solved it for me. And `"r"` or `'r'` instead of `2`.