# Love2D physics does not trigger collision callbacks

Tags: lua, love2d, physics-engine

I am new to Love2D programming, so the answer may just be under my nose.

I am trying to code a collision test for a game which involves a dynamic "player" object (the only fixture with a collision function) moving with a fixed linear velocity in a world without gravity. At the centre of the screen is a static disk. When the player enters the disk, its linear velocity should be set to a higher value.

However, none of the collision callbacks are called at all. The simulation runs with no errors but the player does not change velocity. I have tried with other collision function (e.g. print text in console, change callback function) but none of them got called. I have also formatted the collision callback code in the same as a tutorial game and the detection did work with no problems.

Here are the code files

```
--world.lua
local function begincon(fa, fb, col) 
    local enta = fa:getUserData()
    local entb = fb:getUserData()
    if enta.begcon then enta:begcon() end
    if entb.begcon then entb:begcon() end
end

local function endcon(fa, fb, col) end

local function presol(fa, fb, col) end

local function postsol(fa, fb, col) end

local wld = love.physics.newWorld(0, 0, false)

wld:setCallbacks(begincon, nil, nil, nil)

return wld
```

```
--player.lua

local wld = require('world')
local state = require('state')
local bit = require('bit')

return function(pox, poy)
    local player = {}
    player.body = love.physics.newBody(wld, pox, poy, 'dynamic')
    player.body:setLinearVelocity(-100, 0)
    player.body:setMass(50)
    player.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(10, 20)
    player.fixt = love.physics.newFixture(player.body, player.shape)
    player.cat = tonumber('1000', 2)
    player.msk = tonumber('0011', 2)
    player.fixt:setFilterData(player.cat, player.msk, 0)
    player.fixt:setUserData(player)

function player.begcon(self) --supposed to resolve collision
    self.body:setLinearVelocity(-200, 0)
end
end
```

Comment: you're missing an `end` in player.lua  this code should cause errors rather than not being executed

Comment: sorry, the 'end' was in the code but not in the post. I have edited it.

Comment: It looks like the problem is not in the presented code (or it's hidden through e.g. collision mask or categories; I could bet on problem in player vs disk sensor/category/mask issue). You mentioned that if you just copy example it works out fine. I suggest to create [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help you (and us) to identify the issue properly.

Comment: Could you post your whole program? Including the main.lua? Either on here or on a github and then link the Github? Also I'm not sure but it sounds like this might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/53699758/6331353 .