# Check collision of ball with brick and undo the brick area to blank space and reverse the x velocity

Tags: lua, love2d

For making my project I want the ball to reverse the velocity when hit with the brick and erase that particular brick but can't get to work with the knowledge i have.
EDIT - Found the solution https://github.com/itswaqas14/brickBreaker

```
block_pos  = {}  --  table to store block positions
    rows, columns  = 30, 20  --  you decide how many

    chance_of_block  = 75  --  % chance of placing a block

    block_width  = math .floor( VIRTUAL_WIDTH /columns )
    block_height  = math .floor( VIRTUAL_HEIGHT /rows )

    col  = columns -1  --  don't loop through columns, just use final column

    for  row = 0,  rows -1  do

        if love .math .random() *100 <= chance_of_block then
            local xpos  = col *block_width
            local ypos  = row *block_height

            block_pos[ #block_pos +1 ] = { x = xpos,  y = ypos }
        end  --  rand

    end  --  #columns
```

and for printing the generated block in `love.draw()`

```
    for b = 1, #block_pos do
        local block  = block_pos[b]
        love .graphics .rectangle( 'line',  block.x + 5,  block.y,  5,  10 )
    end  --  #block_pos
    -- random 2nd line of blocks
    for b = 1, #block_pos do
        local block  = block_pos[b]
        love .graphics .rectangle( 'line',  block.x - 5,  block.y,  5,  10 )
    end  --  #block_pos
```

All this is in main.lua since I am not familiar with Class concept in java and I have written a basic collision function in ball.lua which is imported in main.lua and I also have written paddle.lua for controlling the paddle

```
    if self.x > box.x + box.width or self.x + self.width < box.x then
        return false
    end

    if self.y > box.y + box.height or self.y + self.height < box.y then
        return false
    end
    
    return true
end
```

Comment: what is your question? what do you expect your code to do, what does it do instead? what is wrong with the many collision examples available online? please read [ask]

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53699758/6331353)

Comment: @Sam, unfortunately, no because it shows something about the mouse and I only know to take input from keyboard and mouse input is not required for my project too

Comment: @Piglet I know the logic of many collision examples available online but it doesn't help my problem. I expect the code to erase the brick when the ball collides with the brick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how big is that ball?  you need to add the radius to your collision detection.  you could use pythag a² +b² = c² IF you absolutely need diagonal precision, but it's faster without.  and at that scale, it's only one or two pixels, so you won't even notice.

```
--  right side of ball  >  left side of box  or  left side of ball  <  right side of box
if ( self.x +self.radius > box.x -box.width or self.x -self.radius < self.width +box.x )

--           top of ball  <  bottom of box    or     bottom of ball  >  top of box
and ( self.y -self.radius < box.y +box.height or self.y +self.radius > self.height -box.y ) then

    block = nil  --  collision detected, get rid of block at that [index] location   
                 --  block_pos[b] = nil    however you have it worded in this region of code

    ball.dirX = -ball.dirX  --  not sure how you are keeping track of ball direction,
                            --  but make vector reflect here
end
```

Comment: The ball is a square with side 6. The problem is that I don't have any relation between the bricks and the term ```box.x or box.width``` etc its just defined at a particular x and y co ordinate while I have defined ball.lua and paddle.lua which has box.x, box.width etc mapped to its x y and length and width. So the collision function becomes invalid for checking with the brick because the bricks doesn't have any value indexed to its box counterpart

Comment: well, you only ever have to start checking for wall collisions when `ball.x > first wall position`, so once it's there, you'll need to **loop through every brick** to test if the ball is touching.  you can speed this process up by only testing for bricks that are near it; say all bricks in the top half of the screen, or all bricks in the middle, or all bottom half.  sort of like binary space partitioning.

Comment: and how do i revert the brick to empty space again so that if the ball comes in the area of that brick it goes ahead rather than reversing its velocity?

Comment: once you set that block to `nil`, it won't have any effect on the ball.  it's overwritten, or overridden, however you want to call it, but the initial values no longer exist, so they won't have any influence any more;  either on the ball, or the draw() function.

Comment: after i run your answer it says attempting to index 'self' a global variable a nil value so I changed the self.x to ball.x and all terms to ball since all this is in main.lua and then it gave me the same error but now for 'box' so I changed box.x to block since I don't have box defined for brick in my program but it give the same error again but now for 'block' even though my block.x is defined

Comment: here is the link to my code https://github.com/itswaqas14/brickBreaker