# Mouse press bug in love2d lua

Tags: lua, love2d

The below is a self-explanatory love2d program sample of mine. The variable 'state' determines the state of the game, i.e, 'play' & 'menu'. The initial state is 'menu' and what is expected to happen here is when first right-clicked, the state changes to 'play', and on further second right-click the variable printMsg is set to true as a result of which a message is printed inside function `love.draw()`.

```
function love.load()
    state = 'menu'
end

function love.draw()
    if printMsg == true then
        love.graphics.print('mousepressed')
    end
end

function love.mousepressed(x, y, button)
    if state == 'menu' and button == 1 then
        state = 'play'
    end
    if state == 'play' and button == 1 then
        printMsg = true
    end
end
```

I have 2 issues here:

1. On the first click itself the message is printed because the program tends to think that the first click is also the second click.
2. Without having to create a variable `printMsg` to actually print the message, I want to print the message at the instance the button is pressed. What I mean is:

```
function love.load()
    state = 'menu'
end

function love.draw()
end

function love.mousepressed(x, y, button)
    if state == 'menu' and button == 1 then
        state = 'play'
    end
    if state == 'play' and button == 1 then
        love.graphics.print('mousepressed')
    end
end
```

but unfortunately, this prints nothing.

Comment: For how long should the text be displayed? What should happen if I click for a third time?

Comment: the text should display as long as the state='play'. there is no action for third click.

Comment: [Does this answer help you out at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53699758/6331353)

Comment: Thanks but its a completely different topic

Comment: Then using `elseif` with your original code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You enter the second if statement because you assign `'play'` to `state`. hence the condition of the second if statement is true.

If only one of those things should happen:

```
if state == 'menu' and button == 1 then
  state = 'play'
elseif state == 'play' and button == 1 then
  love.graphics.print('mousepressed')
end
```

or

```
if button == 1 then
  if state == 'menu' then
    state = 'play'
  elseif state == 'play' then
    love.graphics.print('mousepressed')
  end
end
```

or if you can only have those two options you can omit one of the conditions:

```
if button == 1 then
  if state == 'menu' then
    state = 'play'
  else
    love.graphics.print('mousepressed')
  end
end
```

Note that this print will not result in any output. By default Love2d will clear the screen befor invoking love.draw. So anything you print outside love.draw is not taken into account.

Either exclusively draw in love.draw or avoid clearing the frame buffer by implementing your own love.run.

Comment: this doesn't print the message

Comment: see edit. you should spend more time with the manuals. make sure you know how a love game works and how it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The standard color for text is: Black
And the standard color for background is: Black
I guess therefore it is printed but you cant see it.
Try `love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1)` before `love.graphics.print()` in `love.draw()`.
( Before each drawable )

Look: https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.setColor